# Deleting lines matching certain condition from sql column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 as backend. One of the tables in the database has a field of type text. There is only one field in the table.
This table is populated by an application which puts a list of strings in the single text field. For some reason the application has started putting some strange characters within the text. So it appears as a single special character in one of the line in the text.
For eg:

```
abc
def
$
ghi
&
jkl
```

Now the entire above string is stored in a column entry and there are many such entries.
I wanted to know how can i write an sql update or replace query to strip the special characters from the column entry. So after running the query, the output in a row should be

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are the special characters limited to '$' and '&', or a somewhat small list?

Comment: Are the strings which are *good* in this place members of an existing list? Or put in other words: How should some logic know, which entries are good and which are bad?

Comment: no there are lot of other characters like `, ~, Ÿ, Š. But one thing common is that they are single characters and I am ok with deleting anything that has length of 1 character.

Comment: Do you own the table?  If so, I would change the data type to nvarchar(max).  Aside from text being deprecated (most likely in 2016), it should help prevent the addition of special characters.

Comment: @Shnugo anything that is of single character can be considered bad. Even if it is A, B or 3 for eg.

Comment: @user2538042 no I do not own the table. I have already notified the application developer about this issue. But I want a quick fix to change the existing content in the table. I do not want to lose the rest of the data.

Comment: Your example above is all kept in a single cell?  Or 6 cells in one column?

Comment: @AaronD sorry for not being clear earlier. Yes the table has only one text field. And the example above is kept in a single field/cell

Comment: Hi, please see my edited answer

Comment: Well now I'm confused. I haven't been doing this very long, so excuse my ignorance. But what would be the purpose of having line breaks in a column?

Comment: Besides the fact, that it is quite normal to have broken text in one column, I see in my daily live a lot of data, which might be put in better structures. But this list seems to come from an outside tool and the OP has no other choice than to take it "as is"...

Comment: Is this question still open? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @LineBreak VARCHAR(2)=CHAR(13)+CHAR(10); --might be only 10 or only 13...

DECLARE @yourString VARCHAR(MAX)=
'abc
def
$
ghi
&
jkl';

SELECT The.Parts.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM (SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@yourString,'<','&lt;'),'>','&gt;'),'&','&amp;'),@LineBreak,'</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS MyString(AsXml)
CROSS APPLY MyString.AsXml.nodes('x') AS The(Parts)
WHERE LEN(The.Parts.value('.','varchar(max)'))>1
```

If you need the result again concatenated to a line broken single string, use this select

```
SELECT REPLACE(STUFF
(
    (
    SELECT 'HereTheLineBreak' + The.Parts.value('.','varchar(max)')
    FROM (SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@yourString,'<','&lt;'),'>','&gt;'),'&','&amp;'),@LineBreak,'</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS MyString(AsXml)
    CROSS APPLY MyString.AsXml.nodes('x') AS The(Parts)
    WHERE LEN(The.Parts.value('.','varchar(max)'))>1
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,16,''),'HereTheLineBreak',@LineBreak)
```